# How to use css to create card border with Shape

Tags: css, shapes

I want to create this card with border using shape css or any other possible option. Is it possible? Is there any inside negative border for such a shape?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK0gF.jpg)

and i want the card like this one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ0ov.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try to play with some shapes in css like this?

Some "dirty" solution:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.shape-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.left-box {
  position: relative;
}

.negative-box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.top {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
}

.bottom {
  width: 60px;
  height: 90px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.right-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shape-container">
    <div class="left-box">
      <div class="negative-box"></div>
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```